# Engine starts but almost immediately cuts out 3 or 4 times when starting

Tags: fuel-system, ignition, golf, idle

I have a Golf Mk1 that has been sitting a while and I am fixing up. When I start the car the engine catches but then dies almost immediately. I have to restart the car 3 or 4 times like this until the engine starts idling.

Could this be because of stale fuel? I havent replaced the fuel in the tank yet (been sitting for over a year).

Or could this be something to do with the injection?

Comment: Yes, change the fuel. Have you tried to check the fuel pressure during this start procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research and found this can be caused by a dirty throttle body. I removed the air intake piping and cleaned the butterfly valves with throttle body cleaner. All good now!